# How can I select the Email Address of the Account Owner connected to an Opportunity?

Tags: soql, query, opportunity

I am struggling to use SOQL to get the Email field of the User which owns the Account which owns an opportunity.

**Can I write a SOQL statement to get this directly?**
I seem to have trouble putting the SOQL together. What I want is something like:

```
SELECT Email FROM User
WHERE User.Id = (SELECT Account.OwnerId FROM Opportunity
                 WHERE Opportunity.Id in:OppIds);
```

This is in Apex, so I could write a loop etc. to solve.

Comment: Do you want the email address of the Owner of Opportunity records? OR Do you want the email address of the Owner of Account record in the Opportunity record? Please do correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch the Email Address of Owner of Opportunity records

```
SELECT Owner.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Id in:OppIds
```

To fetch the Email Address of Owner of Account in Opportunity records

```
SELECT Account.Owner.Email FROM Opportunity WHERE Opportunity.Id in:OppIds
```

Comment: Why did I find that so difficult? Doh. Note, result is List<Opportunity>

Comment: You can fetch the Email address using a for loop. even if you will use User object, then the result will be List<User>

Comment: I'm good with a List<Opportunity> as I'm going to email each one from the email address just obtained.